# Wrap column using ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using ng-repeat to print an array in my controller. My problem is that i want my repeat to start listing from the top after my n:th item, like this:

```
 Item 1    Item 6    Item 11
 Item 2    Item 7    Item 12
 Item 3    Item 8    Item 13
 Item 4    Item 9    Item 14
 Item 5    Item 10   Item 15
```

My code:

HTML

```
<div class="participant-list" >
    <div class="participant" ng-repeat="speaker in participants | orderBy:'name'" ng-click="addSpeaker(speaker.id)">{{speaker.name}}, {{speaker.city}}</div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.participant-list {
    height: 800px;
}

.participant {
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Could use the column property if I understand your question correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/mbnmL67m/

Comment: That is probably not a very good idea as the browser support is not that good.

Comment: Column property works fine for now, I just need it for something interal tomorrow and need to fix it asap.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the most elegant solution, but it works. It does not work if the number of items is not a multiple of three (or however many columns you want). To fix that you could add blank items to the array. You will also have to sort it in the controller manually.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>NG Repeat Column Wrapping</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./ctrl.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in rowsCount">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span>{{ names[$index] }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span>{{ names[$index + 5] }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <span>{{ names[$index + 10] }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

ctrl.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["Bob", "Susan", "Mark", "John", "Billy", "Ted", "Marcy", "Wilma", "Jeff", "Yasmin", "Pete", "Taylor", "Matthew", "Laney", "Jesus"];
  $scope.rowsCount = [];
  $scope.createRows = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < ($scope.names.length / 3); i++) {
      $scope.rowsCount.push(i);
    }
  };
  $scope.createRows();
});
```